# I want to search products of current location as well as of nearby location

Tags: php

Table1 i.e Location

```
Id Name     Nearby
1  vashi    Ghansoli 
2  Ghansoli vashi
3  CBD      Nerul
```

Table2 Brands

```
Id  Name    Location
1   puma    vashi
2   nike    ghansoli
3   addidas CBD
4   nike    Nerul
```

SO I've created tables like this and when i search a location it directly goes to the session.

So what I want when I search **vashi** it should reflect **puma,vashi** as well as **nike,ghansoli** as ghansoli is in nearby of vashi

I'm using code

`select * from brands where Location IN ('vashi', 'select Nearby from location where Name = vashi')`

Comment: What is your question? Does the code giving an error, or not the desired results (and if so, what is the current result)? Try to be as clear as possible when writing a question, so others don't have to guess what your actual problem is.

Comment: I want search brands from current location and should also get brand of nearby location. And the code is also showing brand of current location not of nearby  location.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is really close. All you need to do is to treat the result of the subquery as a scalar value, by wrapping it in brackets:

```
select * from brands where Location IN (
  'vashi',
  (select Nearby from location where Name = 'vashi')
)
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/243235/2 for a demo